# Unity3D: How to make effect that cut avatar into pieces

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, avatar

I'm new to Unity3D, after several official tutorials I got some basic understanding about Unity3D. Now I would like to have fun with making my game.

I would like to have a sword cut an avatar into pieces. Like the game "Fruit Ninja", cutting fruit into pieces.

The specific effect I want: the cutting should be according to sword-cutting-angle, in other words, **the breaking-pieces effect should vary according to every cut**, that feels real.

**My thought**: since Avatar is made by Mesh Filter, if I cut the avatar by waist, into two pieces(upper body, lower body), I should use code to make two Mesh Filter to hold the two pieces.

I'm not expecting very detailed code, that could be a lot. I'm just wondering if I could get a clue about how to make this effect. Because I think **"cutting avatar into piece"** should be a general effect in game.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy as you may think...
[Here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/57994-Simple-Fracture-Script-v-1-01?highlight=procedural%20destruction) you can get one approach to the solution:

> it clones the object, finds a plane based on user variables, and flattens all the points on the other side of the plane onto it, then repeats this with the clone and the other side of the plane.

Other approach could come from using shaders, search for "cut away view shader".

I hope I have given you the start kick